# MySQL - Service Name in Windows

Tags: mysql, powershell, windows-server

What is the MySQL service name?

```
Get-Service | where{$_.name  -like "*MySQL*"}
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `Get-Service` and the `-Name` property to find the exact server name. It has the same effect as doing the search with `Where-Object` but is less typing.

```
Get-Service -Name MySql
```

or just

```
Get-Service MySql
```

If you want to start or stop the service you can pipe that to the appropriate command

```
Get-Service MySql | Stop-Service
```

Answer (score 0):

User the [sc (Service Control)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) command and pipe output to [find](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906.aspx) command

```
sc queryex type=service state=all | find /i "MySQL"
```

Please note that this does not require powershell